# Java CheckboxMenuItem get/setState

Tags: java, checkbox, awt

I am using this to create a quick menu in my Java system tray app.

```
    Menu notiSET = new Menu("Benachrichtigungen");
    CheckboxMenuItem ns1 = new CheckboxMenuItem("On");
    CheckboxMenuItem ns2 = new CheckboxMenuItem("Off");
```

I would like to set Checkbox `ns1` to `true` by default.

[image]

Using `ns1.setState(true);` doesnt work - I can only change the state by clicking it.

I tried using `.setSelected();` or `isSelected();` which doesnt work as well (methods not known).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why use AWT?   See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/6255978#6255978) for many good reasons to abandon AWT components in favor of Swing.

Comment: @AndrewThompson thank you for the hint - it is for final exam and asked to use it this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your menu items live together within that menu.

So: don't tell a single item that it should be selected; instead turn to that menu **group** and tell that object which of its entries should be the default.