# Java CheckboxMenuItem get/setState entries

Tags: java, menu, awt

I asked a few hours ago [(see: Java CheckboxMenuItem get/setState)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42762495/java-checkboxmenuitem-get-setstate)
 how I can change the state from my `CheckBoxMenuItem`.

The user `GhostCat` correctly suggested to me that in order to change the state I have to tell the object's entries its values.

My Menu:

```
Menu notiSET = new Menu("Benachrichtigungen");
CheckboxMenuItem ns1 = new CheckboxMenuItem("On");
CheckboxMenuItem ns2 = new CheckboxMenuItem("Off");
```

I tried using `notiSET.countItems()` which gives me correctly `2` as an answer.
Following that I used

```
System.out.println(notiSET.getItem(0));
System.out.println(notiSET.getItem(1));
```

to identify the entries.

Output:

```
java.awt.CheckboxMenuItem[chkmenuitem0,label=On,state=false]
java.awt.CheckboxMenuItem[chkmenuitem1,label=Off,state=false]
```

Now I am trying to change the value of `state=false` from `chkmenuitem0`.

I tried using `notiSET.getItem(0).`**setState(boolean)**`;` but the method is not known.

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: didn't you forget to cast your  notiSET.getItem(0) to CheckboxMenuItem ? cause getItem return a JMenuItem not a CheckboxMenuItem

Comment: @basslo I think what I wrote is correct - using `notiSET.getItem(0).setLabel("test");` changes the value from `On` to `test`

Comment: CheckboxMenuItem is a subclass of JMenuItem so it inherits the setLabel method from it that's why it works. But JMenuItem doesn't have setState(boolean ) method.

Comment: Look at the answer below. It is possible. You only have to cast your JMenuItem to CheckboxMenuItem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should cast your JMenuItem returned by getItem into CheckboxMenuItem like that :

```
((CheckboxMenuItem)notiSET.getItem(0)).setState(boolean)
```

Comment: This works great! Is this a legit workaround or tricking? Thanks for helping!

Comment: it is just casting! To cast you should be sure that the item is from the good type otherwise it will throw a exception.

Comment: @bassio Thank you for helping and giving an explanation. You helped me a lot.